# A phrase to cover the meaning of "crawlers generated by crawlers"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing a crawler(web crawler). While crawling, the crawler will generate other crawlers(objects which have a simple and unit[do one thing] crawling function, except to generate other sibling crawlers when needed, once triggered). And it will expire once being used. Any proper names for such an object?

Comment: Because it can't create/instantiate any other instances, the relationship is more like a master-slave one than parent-child to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the verb **spawn** and the noun **spawn**.

> The main crawler *spawns* other crawlers.

"to spawn a process" is a metaphor often used in computing.  But to refer to these secondary crawlers as "*the* spawn" of the first would be a little playful. A quite legitimate, serious use would be "the *spawned* crawlers".

Answer (score 0):

The word **"[children](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/child)"** can be what you are looking for!

The **"crawler"** in this case will be the *parent* of the child it created.

According to your comment the word **"[brood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brood)"** can be of help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I thought it would be better to name it after a kind of animal. Children can be children of anything with any characters.

Comment: You can then say "brood"

Answer (score 0):

The term that comes to my mind is a **worm**. A worm is a computer program that replicates functional copies of itself and spreads to other computers, usually to cause some type of damage.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm

It's usually a type of malware though, rather than the innocent web-crawler that you describe....